# tcolorbox: problem with alignment of text

Tags: align, tcolorbox, alignment

I have created 3 tcolorbox, one left, one right and one down. The idea is for the text to be at the left of the graph, at the right and below of the graphs ( I included the graphs so it can be better explained.

The problem I can't fix is the alignment. I want the text justified in the 3 cases (keft, right and down), but all I get is flush left text.

I hope this makes sense, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{parskip}

\geometry{letterpaper, portrait, margin=1.3in} 
% esto es para las cajas con los gráficos 
\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigureright}[2][]{%
    float=htb!,blend before title=colon hang,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=yellow!50!black,colbacktitle=yellow!75!black,title={#2},every float=\centering,halign=flush center,halign lower= left,sidebyside align=top seam,lower separated=false,sidebyside,righthand ratio=0.4, valign lower=top
    #1}
\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfiguredown}[2][]{%
    float=htb!,blend before title=colon hang,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=yellow!50!black,colbacktitle=yellow!75!black,title={#2},halign=flush center,halign lower= left,lower separated=false,  valign lower=top,
    #1}
\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigureleft}[2][]{%
    float=htb!,blend before title=colon hang,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=yellow!50!black,colbacktitle=yellow!75!black,title={#2},halign lower=center,halign=left,sidebyside align=top seam,lower separated=false,sidebyside,righthand ratio=0.666,
    #1}

\title{book 1}
\author{jmv }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{graficos con texto abajo, izq, der}
\newpage

\begin{myfigureright}{RIGHT}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.04]
%titulo
\node [above] at (60,120) {$\textrm{Mercado de los lápices}$};
%ejes
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,120) node[above left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(150,0) node[below right]{$Q$};
%Curvas
\draw(0,100)--(100,0) node [right] at (90,10) {$Dda$};
\draw(20,0)--(120,100) node[right]{$Of$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
Solución al equilibrio de mercado en el mercado de los lápices, representado por:
\begin{align*}
Q^D&=100-P\\
Q^O&=20+P    
\end{align*}

\lipsum[1]
\end{myfigureright}


\begin{myfiguredown}{DOWN}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.04]
%titulo
\node [above] at (60,120) {$\textrm{Mercado de los lápices}$};
%ejes
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,120) node[above left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(150,0) node[below right]{$Q$};
%Curvas
\draw(0,100)--(100,0) node [right] at (90,10) {$Dda$};
\draw(20,0)--(120,100) node[right]{$Of$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
Solución al equilibrio de mercado en el mercado de los lápices, representado por:
\begin{align*}
Q^D&=100-P\\
Q^O&=20+P    
\end{align*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myfiguredown}

\begin{myfigureleft}{LEFT}

Solución al equilibrio de mercado en el mercado de los lápices, representado por:
\begin{align*}
Q^D&=100-P\\
Q^O&=20+P    
\end{align*}
\lipsum[1]

\tcblower
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.04]
%titulo
\node [above] at (60,120) {$\textrm{Mercado de los lápices}$};
%ejes
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,120) node[above left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(150,0) node[below right]{$Q$};
%Curvas
\draw(0,100)--(100,0) node [right] at (90,10) {$Dda$};
\draw(20,0)--(120,100) node[right]{$Of$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{myfigureleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\justify{\lipsum[1]}` with `\usepackage{ragged2e}` works to justify

Comment: @jsbibra justification is the default so you almost never need to specify it, and the package `\justify` command is like `\center` and does not take an argument, so the form you show would apply to the rest of the document or environment  and it is the internal form of the `justify`  environment. the command form (when it is used) is `\justifying` which has the same syntax as `\centering` which again does not take an argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I am doing something in my code that is breaking the justification by default? Thanks

Comment: @jmvicuna yes you are using `every float=\centering` which puts `\centering` at the start. You could use ragged2e's `\justifying` to set it back but I think it is clearer if you avoid setting that in the tcolorbox option and explicitly center the parts you want to center by using `\begin{center} \end{center}` around them.

Comment: unrelated but I wouldn't use `float=htb!` not including `p` makes it more likely to go to the end, and including `!` which means "ignore the default settings, just for this float" is a slightly inconsistent thing to have as a default

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the input, in the end the halign=left was the cause of the problem! I found it with your comments (and posted in an answer if anyone have the same issue).

Answer (score 2):

I found what the problem was, I was using

```
halign=left,
```

And that was the cause of the problem. As suggested by @David Carlisle, the justified was the default setting, so I was overriding it with this command.

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\justify{\lipsum[1]}` with `\usepackage{ragged2e}` works to justify

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\geometry{letterpaper, portrait, margin=1.3in} 
\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfiguredown}[2][]{%
    float=htb!,blend before title=colon hang,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=yellow!50!black,colbacktitle=yellow!75!black,title={#2},halign=flush center,halign lower= left,lower separated=false,  valign lower=top,
    #1}
\begin{document}

\begin{myfiguredown}{DOWN}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.04]
%titulo
\node [above] at (60,120) {$\textrm{Mercado de los lápices}$};
%ejes
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,120) node[above left]{$P$}--(0,0)--(150,0) node[below right]{$Q$};
%Curvas
\draw(0,100)--(100,0) node [right] at (90,10) {$Dda$};
\draw(20,0)--(120,100) node[right]{$Of$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
Solución al equilibrio de mercado en el mercado de los lápices, representado por:
\begin{align*}
Q^D&=100-P\\
Q^O&=20+P    
\end{align*}
\justify{\lipsum[1]}
\end{myfiguredown}


\end{document}
```

Comment: as I commented above `\justify{...}` is incorrect syntax.